# При запуске появляется очень быстро черный экран

Tags: flutter, dart

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 Widget build(BuildContext) {
  return MaterialApp(
   title: 'Weclome',
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Welcom to Flatter'),
    ),
    body: Center(
     child: Text('Hello World!'),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

После компиляции приложения и выполнения его на устройстве Samsung вначале появляется очень быстро черный экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

затем нормальное окно, но в правом верхнем углу корчневая полоса с надписью debug.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем, я отключаю Android Studio, приложение остается на телефоне. Когда я его запускаю, черный экран на некоторое время появляется.

**Вопрос:** так и должно быть? Или после создания APK это все закончится? Спасибо.

Comment: `коричневая полоса с надписью debug` намекает на то что вы собрали debug версию, если собрать release версию, то данные проблемы уйдут (возможно).

Answer (score 0):

Для отключения лейблы:

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
)
```

По поводу чёрных экранов, у вас дефолтный код, это возможна проблема самсунгов, было бы хорошо протестить на другом устройстве и результатом поделиться здесь.

Если я правильно понимаю, то релизная версия ничем не отличается от дебажной, разве что не дебажным ключём, [источник](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android).

Comment: `Если я правильно понимаю, то релизная версия ничем не отличается от дебажной` Отличается, во-первых там не присутствует виртуальная машина Dart. Во-вторых убирается весь дебажный код. И ещё добавляется подписи приложения. По этому приложение может по разному вести себя при debug и release версии сборки.